# Change Content With Anchor

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

Is there any easy way to have an anchor change page content when clicked? Would my best bet be to set the content div with JS when the link is clicked? 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes. You're spot on. Look up Ajax for more information if you want the content change without page refresh or query strings if you don't mind a page refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every modern browser (IE8+) supports the hashchange event, you can have your link change the anchor and the hashchange event handler update the content.

HTML:

```
<a href="#newcontent">change content</a>
```

Javascript:

```
    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {
        if (location.hash == "#newcontent")
        {
            ...
        }
    });
```

If you're looking to make a whole webapp on a single page with content changing based on the hash, there are frameworks to help with this - AngularJS, Backbone.js etc.